# Eliminar espacio en blanco dentro de una etiqueta <p>

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy cargando un párrafo a una vista en ***html***. El problema que tengo, es que me esta colocando espacio en blanco dentro de la etiqueta ***p*** de ***html***. Lo cual al leer el contenido de ese párrafo, con ***javascript*** para remplazar el texto no me lo realiza ya que me encuentra este  . Les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

> ***Nota:*** El texto lo estoy insertando, en la base de datos a través de
>   ckeditor. Necesito que sea desde ***php***, el quitar los espacios dentro de
>   la etiqueta. Ya que si lo hago por ***javascript*** no me remplaza el texto
>   completo sino una parte.

**Función php.**

```
public function getParrafo(){
        $tipo = input_post('tipo');
        $obj = $this->pre->get_preguntaId($this->id);
        if($tipo == 27 OR $tipo == 33){
            $texto = strip_tags(trim($obj->contenido),"<p>");
        }else{
            $texto = strip_tags($obj->contenido,chr(13).chr(10));
        }
        $jdata['texto'] = $texto;
        echo json_encode($jdata);
```

> Esto es lo que obtengo del php en el echo.

```
<p>
    La Convención de las Naciones Unidas sobre el Derecho del Mar, el tratado más importante jamás negociado en ese ámbito, es relativamente reciente. Entró en vigor el 16 de noviembre de 1994. Pero sus orígenes se remontan a comienzos de los años cincuenta, época en que se creó la Comisión de Derecho Internacional de las Naciones Unidas, encargada de desarrollar teniendo en cuenta la práctica de los Estados, el derecho internacional, gran parte del cual era necesario redactar.</p>
```

**jquery**

```
    $.post('index.php?c=unidades&f=getParrafo',{id:id,tipo:tipo},function(data){
        $("div#texto0").html(data.texto);
    },'json');
```

**html**

```
<p>
            La Convención de las Naciones Unidas sobre el Derecho del Mar, el tratado más importante jamás negociado en ese ámbito, es relativamente reciente. Entró en vigor el 16 de noviembre de 1994. Pero sus orígenes se remontan a comienzos de los años cincuenta, época en que se creó la Comisión de Derecho Internacional de las Naciones Unidas, encargada de desarrollar teniendo en cuenta la práctica de los Estados, el derecho internacional, gran parte del cual era necesario redactar.</p>
```

> ***Así me la lee javascript***

```
 "

    &nbsp;

    La Convención de las Naciones"
```

Comment: ¿entonces lo que quieres es borrar los espacios en una cadena desde php? No me quedó muy claro

Comment: para reemplazar los espacios en blanco de una cadena en PHP sería `str_replace(' ', '', $micadena);`

Comment: Si solo quiero remplazar los espacio del principio y al finar si utilizo **str_replace** me los remplaza todos

Comment: Al Inicio y al final de la cadena con `trim($micadena);`

Comment: Así lo tengo pero no me lo quita dentro de la etiqueta **p** sino los de afuera de la etiqueta no lo que están por dentro.

Answer (score 1):

Usa [trim()](http://php.net/trim)

```
public function getParrafo(){
        $tipo = input_post('tipo');
        $obj = $this->pre->get_preguntaId($this->id);
        if($tipo == 27 OR $tipo == 33){
            $texto = strip_tags($obj->contenido);
            // borra todo tipo de espacios, al inicio y al final, y concateno las etiquetas removidas
            $texto = "<p>".trim($texto)."</p>";
        }else{
            $texto = strip_tags($obj->contenido,chr(13).chr(10));
        }
        $jdata['texto'] = $texto;
        echo json_encode($jdata);
```

Comment: ya estoy usando el método **trim()** y tampoco.

Comment: ¿Podrias editar tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo de la cadena justo despues de la linea $texto = strip_tags(trim($obj->contenido),"<p>");? Así podremos ver cómo solucionarlo

Comment: Edite la pregunta ya lo puede revisar

Comment: @YoelRodriguez edité mi respuesta

Comment: Hola yo di otra solución lo que es un poco mas compleja que la tuya. Si gusta la publico para que veas pero muchas gracias esta solución es mas sencilla que la que di yo.

Comment: Puedes agregarla si quieres y marcarla como aceptada, como tú decidas

Answer (score 0):

puedes limpiarlo del lado del cliente o del lado del servidor

**del lado del cliente con javascript**

```
data.texto.trim()
```

**del lado del servidor con PHP**

```
$jdata['texto'] = trim($texto , " ");
```

Comment: Gracias pero no me lo quita de ningún modo.

Comment: usastes las dos formas y no funciono?? haz la prueba en modo incognito puede que este usando el cache, actualice la respuesta con un leve cambio

Answer (score 0):

Aquí les dejo la solución que encontré espero que le sea útil a alguien mas. Lo que hice fue crear una función en la cual quito los espacios:

> Función para quitar los espacios

```
    public function getextoarray($texto){
    //Pasmos de string a array por la etiqueta </p>
    $a_texto = explode("</p>", $texto);
    foreach($a_texto as $val){
        $r_texto = '';
        if($val != ""){
            $r_texto = trim(str_replace("<p>","",$val));
            $s_texto .= "<p>".$r_texto."</p>";
        }
    }
    return $s_texto;
}
```

> Integración en la cita original

```
    public function getParrafo(){
    $tipo = input_post('tipo');
    $obj = $this->pre->get_preguntaId($this->id);
    if($tipo == 27 OR $tipo == 33){
        $texto = $this->getextoarray(strip_tags(trim($obj->contenido, " "),"<p>"));
    }else{
        $texto = strip_tags($obj->contenido,chr(13).chr(10));
    }
    $jdata['texto'] = $texto;
    echo json_encode($jdata);
}
```